# How to show and hide icon on on parent div class hover

Tags: css, reactjs

I have below line of code in which SuggestionListItemStyle is providing hover affect

below is the line of code for component

```
 <div key={item.key}
              className={SuggestionListItemStyle.root}
              data-is-focusable={true}
              onKeyDown={(ev: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLElement>) => this.handleListItemKeyDown(ev, item)}>
              <span ><img style={{display: 'inline-block', width: '4%', height: '50%'}} src={this.props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl+"/SiteAssets/test/test.png"} /></span>  
              <div id={'link' + item.key}
                style={SuggestionListStyle()}
                onClick={() => this.handleClick(item)}>
                {item.displayValue}
                 <div className={styles['notify-close']}>   
       <span className={styles['task__remove-icon']}  onClick={() =>this.deleteitem(item)}>Delete</span>
    </div></div></div>
```

code line for hover affect

```
export const SuggestionListItemStyle = mergeStyleSets({
  root: {
    selectors: {
      '&:hover': {
        backgroundColor: DefaultColors.Item.ListItemHoverBackgroundColor,
        
      }
    }
  }
});
```

I have added classes `className={styles['notify-close']}` and `className={styles['task__remove-icon']}` to show and hide from css and its working as expected

```
.notify-close {
height: 28px;
margin-top: -18px;
margin-left: 508px;


}

.task__remove-icon {
  display: none;
  color: red;
}

.notify-close:hover .task__remove-icon {
  display: block;
  //background-color: blue;
}
```

But issue its show and hide not on  full hover but only on particular div hover below is the hover div, can any one help me how should i modify my `SuggestionListItemStyle` class so it show and hide on full hover

```
 <div className={styles['notify-close']}>   
       <span className={styles['task__remove-icon']}  onClick={() =>this.deleteitem(item)}>Delete</span>
    </div>
```